# Auto Increment the value of a cell based on an adjacent sell value plus search last number increment by 1

Tags: excel-formula

Ok I have 2 excel columns
1st column A "Workstream", is a data list with three numbers as a dropdown. 1,2,3
2nd column B "ID", would like to auto-populate based on the selection made from the left adjacent cell + perform a lookup to get the MAX number in the current column and ADD by 1.

For Example:

| Workstream | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | W1-001 |
| 1 | W1-002 |
| 1 | W1-003 |
| 1 | W1-004 |
| 2 | W1-001 |
| 1 | W1-005 |
| 2 | W1-002 |

So when a user selects from the drop-down in column A then Column B auto-populates with something like this

="W"&A:1&"-"

However, in order to complete the value, it needs to do the following:
="W"&A:1&"-" Search for the Max Record in Column B that starts with 1 or whatever value was entered into Column A, then include the next number based on the MAX value selected in Column A

So in the above example, let's say I Enter "2" in column A, then the value that auto-populates in column B would be

| 2  | W2-003

or if I selected 1 from column A given where we left off then the value that would auto-populate in column B would be:

| 1  | W1-006

Comment: Could you clarify what the rule is to differentiate 'W1' and 'W2' prefixes?  Also, the three-digit number on the right is to count the number of instances of the number to the left, up to the beginning of the column?

Comment: The whole premise is to add new rows of tasks to this worksheet, So when a new task is created a user has to select the workstream number from column A drop-down, and then column B auto-generates the task Unique ID. By using "W" and the value selected in A. Then "Hyphen" with the next number depending on he last value. So if there were no records and I added to the first row, and selected "1" then the value would be W1-001. If Added a second task same as prior then the value in column B would be W1-002 so on and so on. If I selected 2 from A then value in B is W2-001. Always increnenting up

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly and you want the format to be "W" followed by number of the workstream (as inferred from the text of your question) try:

`="W"&A2&"-"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, B2), "000")`

[image]

If instead you want the output exactly as shown in the picture you provided, it's even easier:

`="W1-"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, B2), "000")`

EDIT: You might consider pre-dragging the formula to all the rows that you think have the possibility of being impacted so that you don't have to drag the formula each time you add a row. In that case, try:

`=IF(A2="","", "W"&A2&"-"&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, B2), "000"))`

Comment: It kind of works. What I noticed is that if I start with a blank page at say for example A1 and selected 1 from the A1 drop-down list. Then B1 auto-populates with W1-001. Cool, BUT if I now go to A2 and select 1 from the drop-down then B2 changes to W1-001 and B1 Changes to W1-002. I'm trying to go in sequential order starting from the top and working on down through the bottom. Make sense. Some might say well what about when a record gets deleted then the numbers are off. RULE - We never delete a row.

Comment: It should work sequentially and you should be able to keep adding rows with no problem and just drag the formula down. At least if you freeze the row of the first cell (```A$2:A2```) in the range of the ```COUNTIF``` function. You could also add a function that catches blanks, which I have added in my answer as an edit, to prevent having to drag the formula each time you add a row